# Using procedural singleton in PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

What I want to achieve: What I am trying to achieve: The user should initiate the function then he clicks on the form button. If the infos posted matches with the ones in the database then he gets redirected to login.php, otherwise to relogin.php. I want to be able to find a way to prevent the usage of "global" variables within the function if possible.

Problem: It seems it cant read the mysql connection inside my variable as if it were empty or something or am I wrong? Below the errors messages:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt in C:\xampp\htdocs\project_procedural\php\core\login.php on line 22

PHP Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt in C:\xampp\htdocs\project_procedural\php\core\login.php on line 23

PHP Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\project_procedural\php\core\login.php on line 24

PHP Warning: mysqli_stmt_close(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt in C:\xampp\htdocs\project_procedural\php\core\login.php on line 25
```

What I tried: Tried to remove the global keyword and added $connection as a parameter to my login_check function which caused an error. I also read about php define() but which is only used for constants (which it is in this case?) but makes it global. I know there is the OOP way but I want to master the procedural methods first.

Link to my code in -> phpfiddle

Comment: this function `mysql_real_escape_string()` isn't compatible with `mysqli_`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- just corrected it. I was not the cause though.

Comment: Then your `exit();` stops further execution.

Comment: that should read as `mysqli_real_escape_string` and that function requires db connection be passed as the first parameter. So far, that's what I can see. Others may see other errors.

Comment: Also added semicolon after the global variable. It was missing. It works now. Is there any better way other than using global

Comment: yes, pass the db connection to functions and is better. Error reporting would have caught the semi-colon syntax error too.

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string needs first patameter as connection so add connection variable on it `function mysqli_secure($parameter) {  global $connection;
    return mysql_real_escape_string($connection,$parameter);`
}

Comment: @Fred-ii- so like login_check($connection) ? or wouldnt I have to wrap my  connection stuff in a function before I do so

Comment: yes and there are a few ways to go about this. Either use a master function using the db connection, or pass the db connection for all your functions. Using a class would work even better.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did try it with a class once but would like to keep it pure procedural if possible. So I understand that I wrap the entire connection plus the variables inside in a function with a parameter called $connection. Later I apply the function as a parameter inside my login_check() function

Comment: so basicaly login_check(connection_function($connection))

Comment: exactly; try those out. *Cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually killing connection to database, by assigning new value to a variable that contains it.

Also you shouldn't use neither mysqli_secure() nor mysql_real_escape_string() or whatever of the sort.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this with some small tweaks would check for a `username` within the database and check to see if the `password` was correct or not.

```
$formName = strtolower($_POST['formName']);
$formPass = $_POST['formPass'];

$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "Password1", "project");
    if ($con->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $users->connect_error);
        exit();
    };

$login = $con->prepare("SELECT userID FROM users WHERE userName=?");
$login->prepare("s", $formName);
$login->execute();
$login->store_result();
if($login->num_rows > 0) {
    $login->bind_result($userID);
    while($login->fetch()) {
        $pass = $con->prepare("SELECT userPass FROM users WHERE userID=?");
        $pass->bind_param("i", $userID);
        $pass->execute();
        $pass->bind_result($userPass);
        while($pass->fetch()) {
            if(hash_equals($userPass, password_hash($formPass,$userPass))) {
                echo 'Correct Password';
            } else {
                echo 'Incorrect password';
            }
        };
        $pass->close();
    };
} else {
    echo 'Username not found';
};
$login->close();
```

Answer (score -1):

I modified your code a little bit to use mysqli object oriented. After I made a query, I print out the result. Hope it helps.

```
<?php
session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "project";

$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

function login_check() {
    global $connection;
    $no_match = 'Sorry, password and name do not match.';
    $not_found = 'Your login information does not exist within our database.';

    $name = strtolower($_POST['name']);
    $password = $_POST['password'];    

    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT id FROM members WHERE name = ? AND password = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $name, $password);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
    {
        print_r($row);
    }

    $connection->close();
}

login_check();
```